# php eregi() problem

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have this problem with my code, the page is redirecting and wouldn't stop.. The browser stop it because it's redirecting all the time, and I have a **global.php** file that included in all php pages, so I putted this code for the session and it went like what I said

```
if (!session_is_registered('username')) {
    if(!eregi('login.php', $PHP_SELF)) header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Also **global.php** included in **login.php**, but when I start it on the web server of my site, it does what i said before, but on my based server on computer it works fine, so please help me fast

*and sorry for my english..*

Comment: The posix regular expression "module" is deprecated. http://docs.php.net/eregi says: `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.` - use pcre instead, see http://docs.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'login.php') === false) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Both `session_is_registered()` and `eregi()` are deprecated functions and shouldn't be used. Plus, regular expressions are overkill for what you're doing anyways.

Comment: Since OP is using `eregi`, probably `stripos` should be used instead of `strpos`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION('username'))) {
    if(FALSE === strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'login.php')) {
      header('Location: login.php');
      exit();
    }
}
```

Some Suggestions:

- Make sure that you have `session_start()` placed on top of your script
- Use `isset($_SESSION.......`
- Use `strpos` instead of deprecated `eregi`
- Don't use deprecated `session_is_registered`
- Use `exit/die` after header redirect
- It is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` not `$PHP_SELF`
- Use error handling, put these lines on top of your script:

  - `ini_set('display_errors', true);`
  - `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: `display_errors` shouldn't be hardcoded to true. Set it using `php.ini` so you can easily change it when you move between production and development environments.

Comment: @Daniel EgebergL It is to be there for testing his current script :)